# Aligment issue on @Html.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got the code below from here. I wanted to adjust the size of all text box sized on my forms. My issue is that when I go t the edit view, the text alignment of the text is not horizontally aligned in the center until I click in the edit box? How can I make this vertically  center?

Before:

[image]

After just clicking in the text box it aligns correctly:

[image]

Thanks,
EB

```
                    @media (min-width: 768px) {
                        .form-horizontal .control-label {
                            padding-top: 3px;
                            margin-bottom: 0;
                            text-align: right;
                        }

                        .form-horizontal .form-control {
                            height: 25px;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean horizontally and not vertically?

Comment: Sorry yes vertically